# How to import x86asm into Ghidra?

Tags: assembly, x86, ghidra, dos-com

I have some assembly code as a .txt file (i.e. a list of the instructions, stuff like this):

```
00000003  E8D001            call 0x1d6
00000006  A08000            mov al,[0x80]
00000009  0C00              or al,0x0
0000000B  750B              jnz 0x18
0000000D  90                nop
```

How would I import this into ghidra? (i.e. copy the code into the code browser window). I originally started with a .COM file, but I couldn't successfully import into Ghidra. My end goal is to compile it up to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach won't work. Ghidra analyzes machine code, not ASCII text.

Comment: So I should go back and try to import the .COM file into ghidra?

Comment: @Zopolis4 you should employ an assembler to go from assembler code to machine code. Nasm and Fasm are free-of-charge and open source options.

Comment: I already have the machine code, my aim is C.

Comment: @Zopolis4 Analyze the binary executable the code snippet was taken from. The little piece of code shown in your post is meaningless without context.

Comment: What would I load it the executable as? (i.e. what processor, size and compiler?)

Comment: @Zopolis4 Ghidra expects the input to be a well-formed binary file that conforms to a standard like ELF or PE. Ghidra will parse that file, locate the machine code and disassemble it. If you just want to analyze a snippet of machine code that can be done using the Capstone disassembler.